# Interesting MySQL behavior during benchmarking

Tags: mysql, performance, benchmarking, query-performance

I am trying to understand a big different in MySQL performance between SELECTing data right after data population, and several minutes after.

I wrote code that:

1. CREATEs five tables with an integer primary key, some varchar(50) columns, and, for four of the tables - an integer foreign key to the previous table.
2. Populates the tables with random data, e.g. 10k rows per table.

Then, it SELECTs data from all tables in two methods:

Method #1: with LEFT OUTER JOIN, e.g.:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
       Bench1.id AS a_id, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10,
       Bench2.id AS b_id, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10,
       Bench3.id AS c_id, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10,
       Bench4.id AS d_id, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10,
       Bench5.id AS e_id, e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, e10
   FROM Bench1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Bench2 ON Bench2.bench1Id = Bench1.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Bench3 ON Bench3.bench2Id = Bench2.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Bench4 ON Bench4.bench3Id = Bench3.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Bench5 ON Bench5.bench4Id = Bench4.id
    WHERE Bench1.id IN (342, 452, 81, 405, ...)
```

Method #2: with five separate SELECT queries, e.g.:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, a1, a2, a3, ... FROM Bench1
         WHERE id IN (342, 452, 81, 405, ...)
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, b1, b2, b3, ... FROM Bench2 WHERE bench1Id IN (...)
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, c1, c2, c3, ... FROM Bench3 WHERE bench2Id IN (...)
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, d1, d2, d3, ... FROM Bench4 WHERE bench3Id IN (...)
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, e1, e2, e3, ... FROM Bench5 WHERE bench4Id IN (...)
...
```

Both methods yield the same information (but obviously the JOIN's response is larger due to duplicate data).

Now comes the interesting part.
There seems to be **huge** difference in performance, depending on how long after the data population the SELECTs are executed.

If I populate the data, wait for 10 minutes, and then run the benchmark, I get pretty consistent results where the JOIN method is about 40% slower than the multiple-queries.

However, if I populate the data and then run the benchmark immediately - the JOINs become several hundred times slower than the multiple queries (500 times slower is common, I've also seen it being more than 1000 times slower).

I will also mention that the multi-queries performance doesn't seem to be (significantly) affected by the time waited after the population. This seems to affect only the JOINs.

I also tried to reverse the order of SELECTs (i.e. do the multi-queries SELECTs before the JOIN) - it made no difference.

I was able to reproduce this behavior on a local MySQL 5.7 installation, and also on AWS RDS MySQL (when running the code on EC2).

Can anyone explain this behavior? What happens in the few minutes after INSERTing a large amount of data that so drastically affects the performance?

I thought about some kind of background re-build or optimization of the indexes, but if that's the case, why doesn't it affect the multiple queries method? These queries depend on the same indexes...

### UPDATE:

Additional info: CREATE TABLE, SHOW TABLE STATUS, innodb_buffer_pool_size, and RAM size:

#### CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE Bench1 (
    id int(11) NOT NULL,
    a1 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    a2 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    a3 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE Bench2 (
    id int(11) NOT NULL,
    bench1Id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    b1 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    b2 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    b3 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY bench1Id (bench1Id),
    CONSTRAINT Bench2_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (bench1Id) REFERENCES Bench1 (id)
)

CREATE TABLE Bench3 (
    id int(11) NOT NULL,
    bench2Id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    c1 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    c2 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    c3 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY bench2Id (bench2Id),
    CONSTRAINT Bench3_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (bench2Id) REFERENCES Bench2 (id)
)

CREATE TABLE Bench4 (
    id int(11) NOT NULL,
    bench3Id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    d1 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    d2 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    d3 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY bench3Id (bench3Id),
    CONSTRAINT Bench4_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (bench3Id) REFERENCES Bench3 (id)
)

CREATE TABLE Bench5 (
    id int(11) NOT NULL,
    bench4Id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    e1 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    e2 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    e3 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY bench4Id (bench4Id),
    CONSTRAINT Bench5_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (bench4Id) REFERENCES Bench4 (id)
)
```

`

#### SHOW TABLE STATUS

```
Name    Engine  Version  Row_format  Rows   Avg_row_length  Data_length  Max_data_length  Index_length  Data_free  Auto_increment  Create_time          Update_time          Check_time  Collation        Checksum  Create_options  Comment                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Bench1  InnoDB  10       Dynamic     500    163             81920        0                0             0                          2019-01-06 21:36:39  2019-01-06 21:36:39              utf8_general_ci
Bench2  InnoDB  10       Dynamic     4964   320             1589248      0                147456        4194304                    2019-01-06 21:36:39  2019-01-06 21:36:39              utf8_general_ci
Bench3  InnoDB  10       Dynamic     25045  147             3686400      0                540672        4194304                    2019-01-06 21:36:39  2019-01-06 21:36:40              utf8_general_ci
Bench4  InnoDB  10       Dynamic     49914  136             6832128      0                1589248       4194304                    2019-01-06 21:36:39  2019-01-06 21:36:41              utf8_general_ci
Bench5  InnoDB  10       Dynamic     49259  138             6832128      0                1589248       4194304                    2019-01-06 21:36:39  2019-01-06 21:36:42              utf8_general_ci
```

#### SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'

Variable_name            Value
innodb_buffer_pool_size  25769803776

#### RAM size

32GB (on using AWS RDS db.m4.2xlarge)

### UPDATE 2:

Additional info: EXPLAINs

#### Method 1:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE Bench1.id AS a_id, a1, a2, a3, Bench2.id AS b_id, b1, b2, b3, Bench3.id AS c_id, c1, c2, c3, Bench4.id AS d_id, d1, d2, d3, Bench5.id AS e_id, e1, e2, e3 FROM Bench1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Bench2 ON Bench2.bench1Id = Bench1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Bench3 ON Bench3.bench2Id = Bench2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Bench4 ON Bench4.bench3Id = Bench3.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Bench5 ON Bench5.bench4Id = Bench4.id
WHERE Bench1.id IN (27, 315, 429, 371, 126, 104, 3, 176, 376, 128)
```

Yields:

```
id  select_type  table   type   possible_keys  key       key_len  ref           rows   filtered  Extra                                               
1   SIMPLE       Bench1  range  PRIMARY        PRIMARY   4                      10     100.00    Using where                                         
1   SIMPLE       Bench2  ref    bench1Id       bench1Id  5        pm.Bench1.id  9      100.00                                                        
1   SIMPLE       Bench3  ref    bench2Id       bench2Id  5        pm.Bench2.id  4      100.00                                                        
1   SIMPLE       Bench4  ref    bench3Id       bench3Id  5        pm.Bench3.id  2      100.00                                                        
1   SIMPLE       Bench5  ALL    bench4Id                                        49860  100.00    Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

#### Method 2:

(I shortened the `IN()` arguments list for the queries on `Bench2` (and the rest), but the `EXPLAIN` results are of the full queries.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, a1, a2, a3 FROM Bench1 WHERE id IN (271, 480, 422, 431, 256, 491, 440, 496, 225, 456);
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, b1, b2, b3 FROM Bench2 WHERE bench1Id IN (225, 256, 271, 422, 431, 440, 456, 480, 491, 496);
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, c1, c2, c3 FROM Bench3 WHERE bench2Id IN (323, 402, 1254, 1378, 1965, 2153, 2245, 2518, 2756);
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, d1, d2, d3 FROM Bench4 WHERE bench3Id IN (3429, 6746, 13014, 18942, 24579, 2269, 6805, 6850);
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, e1, e2, e3 FROM Bench5 WHERE bench4Id IN (36481, 40044, 11505, 4504, 20798, 4520, 48448, 24305);
```

Yields:

```
id  select_type  table   type   possible_keys  key      key_len  ref  rows  filtered  Extra        
1   SIMPLE       Bench1  range  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  4             10    100.00    Using where  
1   SIMPLE       Bench2  range  bench1Id       bench1Id  5             96    100.00    Using index condition  
1   SIMPLE       Bench3  range  bench2Id       bench2Id  5             484   100.00    Using index condition  
1   SIMPLE       Bench4  range  bench3Id       bench3Id  5             966   100.00    Using index condition  
1   SIMPLE       Bench5  ALL   bench4Id                          49860  100.00    Using where
```

Comment: Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, and RAM size.

Comment: @RickJames `id` is `PRIMARY KEY`. I added all the info you asked for. Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: Eh?  According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html , that is 32GiB, not 3.5?

Comment: @RickJames you're right... I got the number from the "freeable memory" graph, I guess that's wrong. I'm not sure how to physically check this but the instance is indeed `db.m4.2xlarge` so I suppose it has 32GB...

Comment: AWS is good about setting the buffer_pool_size based on the RAM -- 24G vs 32G is  "consistent".  Those are 'tiny' tables.  (Still pondering...)

Comment: Hmmm...  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for Method 1 and for at least Bench1 and bench2 of Method 2.  (Probably all 5 of M2 will be the same.)  5.7 has some new Optimizations, I'm hoping the `EXPLAINs` will give a clue in that direction.  I may then ask for `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Comment: @RickJames I updated the question with the info you requested. Let me know if you also want the FORMAT=JSON version. Thanks!

Comment: @RickJames I can provide an SQL dump and the actual queries that reproduce the issue, if you want. I just tried to re-create from this dump, and was able to reproduce this without using my script. Right after the import - a Method 1 query (with `LIMIT 1`) took `1 row in set (6.33 sec)`, and a few minutes later, the same query yielded: `1 row in set (0.00 sec)`. Method 2 was consistently fast...

Comment: How many items in each IN list?  (Looks like there is a different number.)

Comment: Yeah, I might make a stab at it if you provide the dump.

Comment: @RickJames in the Method 1 query - 10 items in the IN list. In the Method 2 queries - 10, 10, 94, 481, and 988 - respectively. Regarding the dump - I will be able to upload it to S3 and provide a link in an hour or so. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like I remember something about `IN(list)` having a cutoff between multiple probes versus a table scan.  Look at the 988 and Bench5.

Comment: Which version is AWS providing?

Comment: I tested with MySQL 5.7.19 on AWS, and 5.7.16 locally. Not sure I understood the comment about the cutoffs between the multiple probes... I read up a little on multiple probes but I'm not sure I see how it's related...

Comment: @RickJames here are the dump and the test queries: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pubfilexfer/benchmark.zip , in case you are still interested. Thanks!

Comment: 5.6.22 and 8.0.2 consistently give me 0.00s for all queries.  Could something be flushing the buffer_pool between runs (for you)?

Comment: You try to run Method 1 right after populating? I'm not sure how to answer the question about flushing buffer_pool... I don't have code that does that, and both MySQL servers I tested with were dedicated for this and did not do anything else at the same time...

Comment: A big `ALTER` or dump _might_ bump everything out of the buffer_pool.  What mechanism does AWS use for backups?  When does it do it?

Comment: @RickJames it's not related to backups... AWS backs up once a day (and not using dump). This issue reproduces every single time (and I tried many times, every few minutes). Also, it reproduces for me on my local MySQL installation... No ALTERs, dumps, or anything else except the large INSERT INTO queries and the following SELECTs...

Answer (score 0):

In 5.7.4,  `eq_range_index_dive_limit` default raised from 10 (when introduced in 5.6.5) to 200.  This affects IN().

Please experiment with that number in relation to the number of items in the `IN(list)` for Bench5.  I think you will discover the "cause" of the change.

Comment: So this is a possible explanation for why `IN()` would perform better than JOIN, right? But in this case, wouldn't the Bench5 query be expected to perform noticeably worse? Also, why is there such a big difference in performance between running the JOIN immediately after population, and running it a few minutes after?